# How to deal with re-usable connection objects in functional programming (in Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, functional-programming, immutability

How does one deal with persistent objects like socket connections in functional programming?

We have several functions like this

```
function doSomething(argument1, argument2) {
  const connection = createConnection(argument1); // connection across the network
  const result = connection.doSomething();
  connection.close()
  return result;
}
```

Each one recreating the connection object, which is a fairly expensive operation. How could one persist a connection like that in functional programming? Currently, we simply made the connection global.

Comment: Wrap it in an async type (`Task`/`Future`) and pass it around like data?

Comment: @IvenMarquardt I am not exactly sure what you mean?

Comment: First of all, you should pass a connection as a normal argument. If you want to reuse `createConnection(argument1)` across functions, then you can use an object with a lazy getter that creates the connection for each argument only once and when needed. Layzness is key here. You need to understand how a functional `Task` works. It is similar to a `Promise` but has a decisive difference: As opposed to a Promise constructor it doesn't run the async computation immediately but only when you call its `fork` method.

Comment: @IvenMarquardt Thanks for the explanation. In which scope would the connection `Task` sit? Passing it as `argument1` means it needs to be created in the parent (`caller`) scope but in this case it'd make it a global variable.

Comment: Unfortunately it is more involved. A `Task` is just a description of an async computation. `createConnection` is a function that takes an argument and returns a `Task` that describes how it will use this argument to create a connection. You can combine a `Task` with other `Task`s or with functions returning `Task`s. Only when you invoke the `fork` method the connection will be created and the whole composition is run in the encoded order (in sequence or concurrently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is going to have state. Always. Your program is going to do some I/O. Pretty much always. Functional programming is not about not doing those things, it's about *controlling* them: doing them in a way where such things that tend to complicate code maintenance and reason-ability are reasonably confined.

As for your particular function, I would argue that it has a problem: you've conflated *creating a connection* with *doing something with that connection*.

You probably want to start with something more like this:

```js
const createConn = (arg) => createConnection(arg);
const doSomething = (conn, arg) => conn.doSomething(arg);
```

Note that this is easier to test: you can pass a mock in a unit test in a way that you can't with your original. An even better approach would be to have a cache:

```js
const cache = new WeakMap();
const getConn = (arg) => {
  const exists = cache.get(arg);
  let conn;
  if (!exists) {
    conn = createConnection(arg);
    cache.set(arg, conn);
  } else {
    conn = exists;
  }

  return conn;
}
```

Now your `getConn` function is idempotent. And a better approach still would be to have a connection *pool*:

```js
const inUse = Symbol();
const createPool = (arg, max=4) => {
  // stateful, captured in closure, but crucially
  // this is *opaque to the caller*
  const conns = [];
  return async () => {
    // check the pool for an available connection
    const available = conns.find(x => !x[inUse]);
    if (available) {
      available[inUse] = true;
      return available;
    }

    // lazily populate the cache
    if (conns.length < max) {
      const conn = createConn(arg);
      conn.release = function() { this[inUse] = false };
      conn[inUse] = true;
      conns.push(conn);
      return conn;
    }

    // If we don't have an available connection to hand
    // out now, return a Promise of one and
    // poll 4 times a second to check for
    // one. Note this is subject to starvation even
    // though we're single-threaded, i.e. this isn't
    // a production-ready implementation so don't
    // copy-pasta.
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const check = () => {
        const available = conns.find(x => !x[inUse]);
        if (available) {
          available[inUse] = true;
          resolve(available);
        } else {
          setTimeout(check, 250);
        }
      };

      setTimeout(check, 250);
    });
  };
}
```

Now the details of the creation are abstracted away. Note that this is still stateful and messy, but now the *consuming* code can be more functional and easier to reason about:

```js
const doSomething = async (pool, arg) => {
  const conn = await pool.getConn();
  conn.doSomething(arg);
  conn.release();
}

// Step 3: profit!
const pool = createPool(whatever);
const result = doSomething(pool, something);
```

As a final aside, when trying to be functional (especially in a language not built on that paradigm) there is only so much you can do with sockets. Or files. Or anything else from the outside world. So *don't*: don't try to make something inherently side-effective functional. Instead *put a good API on it as an abstraction* and properly separate your concerns so that the *rest* of your code can have all of the desirable properties of functional code.

Comment: Wow, this is a very detailed answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @KerimGüney my pleasure, happy coding!